# How to define a property based on another property

Tags: javascript

I want to define a property to some namespace depending on another property. The following is my attempt to assign `someNameSpace.x2` based on `someNameSpace.x1`:

```
someNameSpace = {
  x1: 100,
  x2: x1 * 0.5,
};
```

but it fails. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that because `x1` hasn't been defined yet in the scope.

```
someNameSpace = { x1 : 100 };
someNameSpace.x2 = someNameSpace.x1 * 0.5;
```

Comment: all of these answers are so ambiguous... i just don't know which method to use :P

Comment: @AndyPerlitch Use a getter, because (1) it's still a property, not a function (2) the value is dependent on the value of x1 (3) the value is live.

Comment: :-/ so much for my attempt at sarcasm... when i first posted that comment all the answers (including mine) were essentially exactly the same...

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference the object in the object literal defining itself.

```
var something = { x: 3 }; 
something.x2 = something.x * 2;
```

You can declare it; then add whatever properties you want after the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

```
someNameSpace = {
  x1: 100,
  get x2(){return this.x1 * 0.5},
};
someNameSpace.x2; // 50
someNameSpace.x1 = 5;
someNameSpace.x2; // 2.5
```

Use a getter instead of cheating like all these other fools. The value of property `x2` is now truly dependent on the value of `x1` :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick using a self-executing function:

```
var someNameSpace = (function(){
    var x1 = 100;
    return {
        x1: x1,
        x2: x1 * 0.5
    };
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T2kyZ/

Comment: @AlienWebguy Yep, just for fun!

Comment: What's the opposite of code golf? code everyOtherSport I suppose, ya? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
someNameSpace = {
    x1: 100
}
someNameSpace.x2 = x1 * 0.5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function that returns the value

```
var NS = {
  x1: 100,
  computeX2: function(){
     return this.x1 * 0.5;
  }
}
```

Some javascript frameworks like ember.js allow you define so-called "computed properties" this way.